# Windows 7 64 bit will not turn monitor off

Tags: windows-7, sleep, wake-on-lan

I just bought myself a new computer (YAY!).
It seems that something is keeping it awake and will not let him turn of the monitor or go into sleep mode.

event when i use "nircmd" (http://nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) an fire the command to turn off the monitor it gose blank for a second and turns on again...

how can I detect the bugger that will not let my new computer sleep ?

So far i have tried: setting "Wake on magic packet", "Wake on pattern match" and "shutdown wake-on-lan" on my network card to disabled but it did not helped so i turned them back on...

Comment: When even the monitor won't standby, test things by removing the Input Devices (temporarily). things stuffed in the USB and PS2, just to see what happens. In the CMDprompt you can get a lot of data using powercfg, so open a cmd and put powercfg /? in and there is lots of stuff there. If you hibernated will that work? Also remember that if the system is just getting going, there is a lot more activity arranging things that eventually reduces some, although that shouldn't matter for this. Don't forget to check your motherboard Bios/uefi too.

Comment: Thank... when i used `POWERCFG -DEVICEQUERY wake_armed` i got 3 devices in the list ... my nework adapter, keyboard an mouse.. so i disabled my network adapter by calling `POWERCFG -DEVICEDISABLEWAKE "Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller"` It still did not help ... could you be more clear as to what i should look for in my BIOS.uefi ?

Comment: The powercfg data can give clues, not proof, and bios(es) are all different. That is why its only a comment. Putting the model and specs of your computer in, gives you some chance that another user has the same machine.  The more info, and things you try and all you edit into the question, the better the answers might be.